# Calligraphy is it a poetry

Tags: poetry, calligraphy

[image]I have a pair of cups ca 40 mm high with a lot of text - is it a poem or just decorative calligraphy? Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is a famous poetry(in nice calligraphy writing) which was written by  [杜甫](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_Fu) regarding his friend [李白](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Bai) and other 7 famous poets who, in his opinion, were "8 Immortals Indulged in Wine" (Yeah it was a thing back then. If you can write beautiful poems while you are drunk, you must be a genius haha). The part on this cup is the part only about 李白.

Both of them are titans of [唐诗](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tang_poetry). Actually they are the best two in most people's opinion. And the best part about their friendship is that 杜甫 is such a Realism poet while 李白 is famous for his Romantic poetic style. Their style are totally opposite yet they cherish each others work and their friendship deeply.

[李白斗酒诗百篇，长安市上酒家眠，天子呼来不上船，自称臣是酒中仙。](https://so.gushiwen.cn/mingju/juv_a91941785020.aspx)

I don't know how to translate it since it is hard to translate poems.

Here is the wikipedia page about this poem:
[饮中八仙歌](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Immortals_of_the_Wine_Cup)

Comment: Li Bai can compose a hundred poems while finishing two liters of wine; Sleeping in a wine house in Chang'an; Refuses to board the ship even the Emperor is calling; Proclaiming this servant of the court is a god of drinking

Comment: @TangHo thank you. I think your translation conveyed the literal meaning pretty good!

Comment: Thank you so much for the information! I bought this pair of wine cups with warmers 2005 and been thinking about the text sins then. Iḿ happy! Wich you a good weekend!

Comment: @StigEklund You are welcome! Enjoy your drinks. If you could, please accept this as the accepted answer so this question can be marked as answered.